Szekeres problem 1.5
In Peter Szekeres's text "A Course in Modern Mathematical Physics", problem 1.5 asks us to prove:
$$
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
  A - \bigcup \mathcal{B} = \bigcup \{A - B_i \mid i \in I\},
\end{equation}
$$
where $\mathcal{B}$ is a family of sets indexed by the set $I$: $\mathcal{B}=\{B_i \mid i \in I\}$.
How can we prove this?

If the downvoter could provide a reason why this is a bad question, that would be helpful.

We cannot prove (1) as it's not true. But we can disprove it. That is, $A - \bigcup \mathcal{B} \neq \bigcup \{A - B_i \mid i \in I\}$. To see that this is the case, consider some $a$ such that $a \in A$, $a \in B_1$, $a \notin B_2, B_3, \ldots$. Clearly, $a \in \bigcup \mathcal{B}$. So, $a \notin A - \bigcup \mathcal{B}$. Additionally, $a \notin A-B_1$, but $a \in A - B_2$, $a \in A-B_3$, etc. Therefore, $a \in \bigcup \{A - B_i \mid i \in I\}$.
We might guess that what Szekeres meant to write was
$$
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
  A - \bigcap \mathcal{B} = \bigcup \{A - B_i \mid i \in I\}.
\end{equation}
$$
We can prove (2) as follows:
$$
\begin{align*}
  A - \bigcap \mathcal{B}
    &= \{x \mid x \in A \land \neg \left[\forall i \in I (x \in B_i)\right]\},\\
  &= \{x \mid x \in A \land \left[\exists i \in I (x \notin B_i)\right]\},\\
  &= \{x \mid \exists i \in I (x \in A \land x \notin B_i)\},\\
  &= \bigcup \{A - B_i \mid i \in I\}.
\end{align*}
$$
If we consult the official solution manual we find that this is the equality he proves. Thus, we can infer that Szekeres meant to write (2) instead of (1).
Unfortunately, there does not appear to be an official errata for this text.

If the downvoter could provide a reason why this answer is incorrect, that would be helpful.

The statement is not true. Take $A = \{1, 2, 3 \}$, and let $\mathcal{B} = \{ B_1, B_2 \}$, where $B_1 = \{ 1, 2 \}$ and $B_2 = \{ 2, 3 \}$. Then $A - \bigcup \mathcal{B}$ = $A - \{ 1, 2, 3 \} = \emptyset$. But $\bigcup \{ A - B_i \}_{i \in \{ 1, 2 \}} = \{ 3 \} \cup \{ 1 \} = \{ 1, 3 \}$.
As you mention in your answer, the intended statement was probably
$$A - \bigcup \mathcal{B} = \bigcap_{i \in I} (A - B_i)$$
which is just one of deMorgan's laws.

I actually proposed a different statement in my answer: $A - \bigcap \mathcal{B} = \bigcup {A - B_i \mid i \in I}$ (i.e., swap the union and intersection). But, I agree the statement you propose is a valid guess for Szekeres's intention (and correct). I think from the official solutions, the alternative statement I gave is probably the one he actually intended, but that doesn't seem too important.
